# Use IAM authentication in EC2 CentOS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I created EC2 instance which is a CentOS box for web application development. Since our developers already have their acccounts in IAM, I feel like it is a duplicate to have local groups and accounts in CentOS. Can I just use IAM accounts for authentication and authorization in the CentOS server? If yes, how?